# Initializing multiset with custom comparison function in C++

Tags: c++, decltype, multiset

Consider following comparison function:

```
bool compare(std::shared_ptr<myObject> &lhs, std::shared_ptr<myObject> &rhs){
   return lhs->value < rhs->value;
}
```

Now idea is to initialize a multiset of type `std::shared_ptr<myObject>` which orders elements with above function. So from book i read it should be done like this:

```
std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<myObject>, decltype(compare)*> myset{compare};
```

**QUESTION:**

My question is, in the declaration i understand a function pointer is passed to refer to compare function, but why are we initializing the set with `{compare}`? What is its importance and why is it necessary to do so like this??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the set needs a comparison functor to work with. If you don't specify one, it will make a default-constructed one. In this case, since you're using a function-pointer type, the default-constructed one will be a null pointer, which can't be called; so instead, you have to provide the correct function pointer at run time.

A better approach might be to use a function class type (a.k.a. functor type); then the function call can be resolved at compile time, and a default-constructed object will do the right thing:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(std::shared_ptr<myObject> &lhs, 
                    std::shared_ptr<myObject> &rhs) const {
        return lhs->value < rhs->value;
    }
};

std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<myObject>, compare> myset;
```

Comment: thanks, after reading jrok comment/answer now i again read your answer and understood your point, earlier i didn't understood (:

Answer (score 4):

`decltype(compare)*` in the template parameter specifies the *type* of the comparator. It doesn't tell *which* function is to be used - whether is it `compare`, `foo`, `bar` or something else. Hence the constructor parameter.

Comment: ins't decltype(compare) refers to type and when we add (*) the whole expression refers to function pointer????

Comment: The parameter is a type - in your case it's the same as `bool(*)(shared_ptr<myObject>&, shared_ptr<myObject>&)`. That doesn't tell anything about which function it is.

Comment: Ok it makes sense but im still confused as to why the actual function needs to be placed in initializing block, to me it is just complex syntax or maybe i still need to study templates?

Comment: @Jason `decltype` queries the type of an expression at compile time while a function pointer itself is an object present at runtime. Perhaps you indeed need to study templates - look up the difference  between type and non-type template parameters.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access your elements, you need to provide function for [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) for your type.

`std::multiset` have the following constructor:

```
 explicit multiset (const key_compare& comp = key_compare(),
               const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

As you can see, you can do this by passing `comp` function pointer (or function object) to the constructor.

---

Answer (score 1):

The comparator passed to the template has to be the type of something that can be called with the function call operator. That would be either a class that has overloaded that operator, or the type of a lambda or a function pointer. In the cunstrutor of set, an instance of that type has to be passed. So `decltype(compare)*` is the function pointer type, and `&compare` is the function pointer.

Comment: but if we are strictly always calling the same function and referring to its type, why we need to specify these separately? can it be that i can refer to type and call a different funtion/lamda etc

Comment: A different lambda: no, because another lambda would have another type. A different function: yes, if it has the same type. That means, you could have two sets of the same type, but the comparator works differently, e.g. with `lhs->value > rhs->value`. The type has to be specified separately, because that's the way templates work - in functions, the template argument may be deduced, but `std::set` is a class, so its not possible there.