# Using comparison function for the key type for sets results in runtime error

Tags: c++, c++11, set, runtime-error, decltype

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718379/initializing-multiset-with-custom-comparison-function-in-c) question and it does not help me.

My question is: Why am I getting a runtime error when using a comparison function for the key type for `set` as below?

```
multiset<Phone, decltype(comp)*> phones { Phone(911), Phone(112) };
              //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In VC2013 it gives me this for the above code:

> Unhandled exception at 0x73DECB49 in debugit.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

Here is a small example that produces the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct Phone {
    Phone(long long const &num) : number{num} {}
    long long number;
};

// compare function:
bool comp(Phone const &n1, Phone const &n2) { return n1.number < n2.number; }

int main()
{   // The below line produces the runtime error.
    multiset<Phone, decltype(comp)*> phones { Phone(911), Phone(112) };
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. I've compiled with VC2013 and g++ (GCC) 4.9.1 both result in the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing multiset with custom comparison function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718379/initializing-multiset-with-custom-comparison-function-in-c)

Comment: You need to give it an instance of `decltype(comp)*`.  E.g. `phones({...}, &comp)`.

Comment: Don't use integers to represent phone numbers. It would fail for mine (and most of the numbers in my country).

Comment: @MikeSeymour what would be better?

Comment: @AndreasDM: `std::string` can contain an arbitrary sequence of digits (including ones, like mine, which begin with `0`). Perhaps put a wrapper around it, if you want to constrain the values to valid phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype(comp)*` is just a pointer to a function with the signature `bool(Phone const&, Phone const&)`. It gets value initialized to `nullptr`. The `std::initializer_list` constructor of [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/multiset) uses this as the default paramter for the `Compare` object. Since you have initialized your `std::multiset` with a null function pointer as the comparator, a call to it likely leads to a segfault.

To fix this, provide a valid instance of the `Compare` object like this:

```
multiset<Phone, decltype(comp)*> phones {{ Phone(911), Phone(112)}, &comp};
```